# Masonry-type Grid Layout in Email

Tags: html, css, email, jquery-masonry

Is this even possible? My site uses Masonry to lay out boxes. I would love to use a similar layout in my digest emails for design continuity's sake.

Has anyone seen this or know if it's even possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

it's not possible to use masonry in email templates.  It's not even reliably possible to use floats.  For maximum client compatibility, you're still stuck with using tables.  And of course with tables, you can't do a proper masonry layout.

Having said that, you can use a simple PHP script to resize each image to a defined size, and then insert those images into a table to go for some semblance of brand uniformity in your emails.

sorry for the bad news

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to implement Masonry layout in the emails. You can take the reference from Mailerstock's email template : 
https://mailerstock.com/email-templates/loki-v1-2-responsive-masonry-grid-email-template/

Note: This template also allows the masonry layout to be responsive on all the device-widths.